# Installable search engine package for file search

Tags: database, unix, search, open-source

Currently there exist package like [gonzui](http://gonzui.sourceforge.net/) (example of the implementation [here](http://b-src.cbrc.jp/)) 
for doing source code search.

Is there a similar package that does the same thing except for simple file search.

Basically I have two list of files for file type A and file type B. When the user type a word
in the search box, all files (in "gz" format) with names match to the search term from type A and B will be displayed.

Is there any ready package that does that?

I am aware of CGI implementation via Perl. But it is difficult for me to have a 
simple and elegant interface/display in it with CGI.

Comment: Generic unix (aka linux) or windows or macosx ?
As Dominik already mentioned there are tools that work on spotlight and MS Technologies. Also do you want file name search or file content search?

Comment: Linux, just file name search.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Omnifind](http://omnifind.ibm.yahoo.net/) which works pretty well.  You might also look into [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) or [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it open-source and/or free? 
Do you need full unicode support?

Also do you want a search or an index? A search does not use any pre-computed information, for every search you have to porcess all the file data.

For an index you would have to pre-process / index the file data.

DTsearch is a commercial  / not free index engine.

The fact that you mention a "database" would indicate to me that you are looking into an index.

There are hooks into the microsoft indexing service and you can also use MsSQL to index text data.

Comment: @DW: Hi Dominik, thanks for the reply. I actually just need a search not index. And I want a open-source/free. It doesn't need a full unicode support.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure I understand what you're looking for, or what your use case is exactly.

However, off the top of my head, there's the `grep` family of tools (`grep`, `fgrep`, `egrep`).

There's also `find`, which I think is more along the lines of what you're looking for.

And if performance matters, there's `locate`, which is based on an index that you will have to update periodically.

All of these come pre-installed with most flavors of UNIX.

I hope this helps.